# Parametrizing a hyperbola in standard position

Tags: conic-sections, parametrization

My text book answer to an exercice:

[image]

$ $

Why is the parameter $t$ $ $ in $ $  $x=2\sec t$ $ $ defined in that interval? $ $   Isn't this preventing $x$ from taking any negative value?

Comment: You are correct.  That parametrization gives only the right branch of the hyperbola.

Comment: So, I'm not missing anything.  Thanks for the confirmation.